# Python 3.6 - separating the columns in multiple lists into new lists

Tags: python, list, reformat

here is my code that counts the number of times unique numbers appear and looks for numbers that repeat 5 times in list A, then any that repeat 2 times in list A as well, and prints the results of any matches of list A with corresponding value from list B. Also list A and B are always the same size.

```
a = (['12','12','12','12','12','23','24','24','31','31'])
b = (['1','2','2','2','2','2','5','5','5','5'])

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(a)

c = []

for ai , bi in zip(a,b):
   if counts[ai] == 5:
       c.append([ai,bi])
   elif counts[ai] == 1:
       c.append([ai,bi])
   else:
       None

print(c)
#[['12', '1'], ['12', '2'], ['12', '2'], ['12', '2'], ['12', '2'], ['23', '2']]
```

Is there a quick way so that my code can reformat the multiple output lists into a list that looks like:

```
#[('12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '23'), ('1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2')]
```

so that each column in each list can have its own list.

Thank you!

Comment: `12` value appears 4 times not 5

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thanks for finding the typo!

Comment: what if `a` would be `['12','24','31,'12','12','23','24','12','31','12]` ? what should be the result?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest For my case, the numbers would increase in value from left to right for list A, however it can be in any order for list B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about that:

```
import itertools

c = [['12', '1'], ['12', '2'], ['12', '2'], ['12', '2'], ['12', '2'], ['23', '2']]

merged = list(itertools.chain(*c))
# merged = ['12', '1', '12', '2', '12', '2', '12', '2', '12', '2', '23', '2']

split = [tuple(merged[::2]), tuple(merged[1::2])]
# split = [('12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '23'), ('1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2')]
```

Answer (score 1):

continuing from your code

```
c = [['12', '1'], ['12', '2'], ['12', '2'], ['12', '2'], ['12', '2'], ['23', '2']]

cols = [] #initialize list of columns
for i in range(2):
  tup = tuple([item[i] for item in c]) #create tuple from loop of column
  cols.append(tup)
print(cols) # [('12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '23'), ('1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension

```
>>> x = [['12', '1'], ['12', '2'], ['12', '2'], ['12', '2'], ['12', '2'], ['23', '2']]
>>> [tuple(v[0] for v in x), tuple(v[1] for v in x)]
[('12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '23'), ('1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2')]
```

It'd probably be more efficient to save your data in the format you want initially. Tuples are immutable so it'd be easier to use lists and append to them. Something like:

```
columns = []
values = []

for ai , bi in zip(a,b):
   if counts[ai] == 5:
       columns.append(ai)
       values.append(bi)
   elif counts[ai] == 1:
       columns.append(ai)
       values.append(bi)

print([columns, values])

# prints this
[['12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '23'], ['1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2']]
```